Thirdweb writeContract not working on hardhat node
Im using local hardhat node for deploying my contracts and using Thirdweb writeContract to execute a registerUser function from my smart contract, I've added the contract address, ABI, clientid and network as Localhost with chain id 1337. Howeover when I execute function s from my frontend, it says the function registerUser does not exist.
Also from thirdweb's dashboard I've setup the local network with correct rpc 127.0.01:8545

this is the part of code where error is taking place on the onclick event of the button, how what is the issue here.
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useEnhancedVotingDAO } from './ContractInteraction';
import { useAddress, useContractWrite } from "@thirdweb-dev/react";

const Homepage = () => {
    const address = useAddress();
    const contractAddress = process.env.REACT_APP_ADDRESS;
    // const contractAddress = "0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3";
    const {
        contract,
        useWriteRegisterUser,
        useWriteRegisterPolitician,
        // useWriteRegisterAdmin
    } = useEnhancedVotingDAO(contractAddress);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("Wallet address ", address);
        console.log("Contract address is ", contractAddress);
        console.log("Contract from Interaction is ", contract);
    }, [address]);
    const { mutateAsync: registerUser } = useWriteRegisterUser("0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3", "registerUser");

    // const { mutateAsync: registerUser } = () => useContractWrite(contract, "registerUser");


    const handleRegisterUser = async () => {
        try {
            console.log("Registering user with address: ", address);
            await registerUser({ args: [] });
            alert("Successfully registered as a voter!");
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error registering user:", error);
            alert(error);
        }
    };

Smart Contract function
  function registerUser() public {
        require(projectVotes[0][msg.sender].weight == 0, "User already registered");
        _userCounter++;
        projectVotes[0][msg.sender].weight = 1; // Use project 0 as a dummy project for user registration
    }


The solution is to deploy your own contracts on the thirdweb local host chain using thirdweb deploy, https://blog.thirdweb.com/thirdweb-deploy/
Ensure to modify the chain Id and RPC URL of the localhost network from the thirdweb dashboard and then deploy the contracts
